# Cargar correctamente BD desde ajax (pasando un JSON)

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo un `json` que pretendo que viaje a traves de `ajax` hacia un archivo `php`, y en este se cargue mi base de datos, pasando cada item del archivo `json` como una nueva fila de la tabla.

**ajax:**

```
    var data = { 'data': JSON.stringify(arrayEventos) }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            alert("response was " + data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorMessage) {
            $("#debug").append("RESPONSE: " + xhr.responseText + ", error: " + errorMessage);
        }
    });
```

**valor de lo que estoy pasando por ajax**

> `data = [{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:00:00"},{"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-13T11:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T12:30:00"}]`

**php donde recibo la variable** `data`

```
<?php

require_once "../modelos/turnos.modelo.php";
class AjaxTurnos{

    public $data;

    public function ajaxActualizarTurnos(){

        $datos = $this->data;


        $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos($datos);

        return $respuesta;

    }

}

/*==============================
    ACTUALIZAR TURNOS
    ==============================*/
    if(isset($_POST["data"])){
        $turnos = new AjaxTurnos();
        $turnos -> data = $_POST["data"];
        $turnos -> ajaxActualizarTurnos();
    }
```

**php que guarda en la base de datos**

```
static public function mdlActualizarTurnos($datos){

    $tabla = "turnos";
    $stmt1 = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("TRUNCATE $tabla");
    $stmt1->execute();

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(datos) VALUES (:datos)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":datos", $datos, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    if($stmt->execute()){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt ->close();

    $stmt -> null;
}
```

> Lo que me sucede es que se guarda en la base de datos TODO el contenido de la variable data en una sola fila:

`ID:1 | DATOS: [{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:00:00"},{"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-13T11:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T12:30:00"}]`

> Cuando lo que yo necesito es que se guarde de la siguiente manera:

`ID:1 | DATOS: {"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:00:00"}`

`ID:2 | DATOS: {"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-13T11:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T12:30:00"}`

> Probe meter un foreach en el `ajax.php`

```
    $datos = $this->data;

    foreach($datos as $key => $value){

        $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos($value);

    }
```

> pero no tuve éxito, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Esto que está dentro del `foreach` no hace lo que quieres: `$respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos($value);`? Si no funciona, pon un `var_dump($value);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: perdon, vos pusiste ese comentario porque yo tenia ``$respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos($datos);`` en el ultimo codigo, que esta dentro de un ``foreach``?? Me confundi cuando escribi la pregunta, en mi codigo le pase ``$value`` (como esta ahora, edite la pregunta) y no funcionó

Comment: @A.Cedano intenté ``foreach($datos as $key => $value){echo '<script>alert('.$value.')</script>';}`` y con ``foreach($datos as $key => $value){var_dump($value);}`` pero no retorna nada por pantalla

Comment: Si observamos lo que dices haber guardado: tienes : ` '[' . cadenajson . ']' ` prueba a hacer : `$datos = json_decode(str_replace([ '[',  ']' ], ['', ''], $this->data) ); `

Comment: edité dos veces el comentario porque olvidé cerrar los paréntesis

Comment: @quevedo es mejor trabajarlos como objetos con las funciones propias para ello. Arriesgarse a hacer reemplazos podría producir datos erróneos.

Comment: Cierto, pero la estructura era clara. Tu respuesta es muy buena.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás recibiendo **un array de objetos JSON**. En JSON array es todo lo que empieza por `[` y termina por `]`, mientras que objeto es todo lo que empieza por `{` y termina por `}`.

Viendo pues la estructura con la que vas a trabajar necesitas:

1. Convertir `$this->data` a JSON para luego poder iterarlo como un array de objetos JSON.
2. Dentro del bucle, obtener cada objeto JSON como una cadena mediante `json_encode` para insertarlo.

Algo así:

```
foreach(json_decode($this->data) as $value){
    $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos(json_encode($value));
}
```

### Prueba de concepto

```
$data='[{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:00:00"},{"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-13T11:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T12:30:00"}]';    
foreach (json_decode($data) as $value){
   echo json_encode($value).PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:00:00"}
{"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-13T11:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T12:30:00"}
```

---

### Observaciones

Veo que haces demasiadas llamadas a `conectar()` puede que ese código necesite ser optimizado seriamente si en cada una de esas llamadas creas objetos de conexión con `new PDO (....)`.

Significa que **por cada fila que insertes estarías creando una conexión**, lo cual sería demasiado costoso. Por eso nunca se debe invocar la conexión desde un método auxiliar que debería servir para insertar, seleccionar, borrar... pero no para conectar. La conexión debería existir a un nivel superior en tu clase.

Comment: Como siempre, funcionó y muchas gracias :)

Comment: Tengo otra duda, como verás, la tabla se trunca antes de guardarle datos. Tuve que hacer la funcion de truncar aparte porque sino solo me guarda el ultimo elemento. Ahora, si yo llamo a esta funcion de truncar la tabla antes de la linea ``$datos = ($this->data);`` yo espero que trunque, y luego guarde uno a uno los elementos. En cambio solo trunca, y no guarda nada. No entiendo lo que sucede, es como si el codigo se detuviera luego de hacer ``ModeloTurnos::mdlTruncarTurnos()``, hay una forma de evitar esto?

Comment: @Mani esa parte del código rechina a los ojos (por lo que te decía de la conexión y por lo de truncar la tabla que me llamó mucho la atención). Propongo que plantees tus dudas sobre eso en una nueva pregunta, explicando un poco el contexto (lo que hace el programa, por qué truncas la tabla, etc). Creo que de ese modo podremos ayudarte mejor a optimizar esa parte porque creo que no es tan simple como decirte *esto o lo otro*. Hay varias cosas que me generan dudas en el manejo que haces en ese método.

Comment: Te agradezco el consejo, como te dije, lo termine separando en dos funciones independientes, y eliminé el close y el null, que entiendo que ya no son necesarias, y anduvo correctamente. Entiendo que si hago una pregunta de ese estilo no seria bien recibida.

Comment: @AgustinG. no tiene por que no ser bien recibida. Estaría basada en algo concreto.